# Convert Datetime to int with select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to convert a timestamp (of type `DATETIME`) to an integer. This I want to do with a SELECT statement:

```
'2016-01-24 08:00:25'---> 20160124080025
```

What is the statement for this conversion?

Comment: Seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: Be carefully, because your output isnt INT, but BIGINT in sql server... SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'yyyymmddHHMMss'))

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

**Output:**
  20160925041023

references:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106901/31995

Comment: Month in upper case and Minute in lower case and it work brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @date datetime
set @date ='2016-01-24 08:00:25'

select cast(format(@date,'yyyyMMhhmmss') as numeric)
```

Comment: IF you using SQL 2012 or above version you can use SQL Format function to get your's desire output

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),120),'-',''),':',''),' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a convertion, You simply want to replace ":", "-" and " " for "".